# No me reproduce el video

Tags: html, video

Hola estoy utilizando 'Apowersoft Online Screen Recorder' para grabar (probé también con otras aplicaciones), lo guardo en formato mp4 pero en la pantalla no me sale el video. Utilizo Opera como navegador predeterminado. Probé con darle tamaño fijo pero tampoco. La ruta del video está bien no se si es por el navegador...

```html
<body>

    <video controls>

        <source src="Apowersoft Online Screen Recorder\Sprint 03 Front End.mp4" type="video/mp4">

    </video>


</body>
```

Comment: Supongamos que la ruta está bien, pero está mal a la vez. Recuerda que para referenciar una ruta en programacion, esta no debe llevar espacios, tampoco el archivo...  Renombra tu archivo y/o carpetass con guiones, algo asi: `<source src="Apowersoft_Online_Screen_Recorder\Sprint_03_Front_End.mp4" type="video/mp4">`  o bien acorta el nombre del folder y del video para que no tengan espacios

Comment: Podrías abrir la consola de desarrollador con F12 y ver si tu ruta en efecto está bien, te saldrá un error 404 en caso de que no.

Comment: Y ese directorio `Apowersoft Online Screen Recorder` está al mismo nivel que el HTML? Y por qué espacios? Todas las URL de recursos deben escaparse para entregar cosas como los espacios en un formato URL-encoded. Por salud mental, evita los espacios

Comment: esta bien pruebo sin los espacios

Comment: VM78:3149 crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated. Esto me muestra en consola

Comment: <body>

    <video controls>

        <source src="C:\Users\Juan\Documents\Apowersoft\Apowersoft-Online-Screen-Recorder\Sprint-03-Front-End.mp4" type="video/mp4" type="video/mp4">

    </video>


</body>
Puse ruta completa sin los espacios

Comment: Dejo el código completo: https://pastebin.com/UP1FnB1U

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo solucioné moví el video a donde tengo la carpeta del proyecto y lo puse junto con las imágenes y luego copie y pegué la ruta. Gracias igualmente por las respuestas.